# What are the best options to store big payloads in automation tests in pytest

Tags: python, json, testing, frameworks, pytest

I have a problem with storing big payloads for testing API. I can't find anything reasonable how to store them and overwrite values. Payloads have 200-300 lines.

Some values are the same in those payloads ( like 5-7 times in one payload), some are constant, and some I have to change with every test run.

Currently I have payloads.py file with variables like

```
scenario_1={
"request1":{200-300 lines payload},
"request2":{200-300 lines payload}

scenario_2={
"request1":{200-300 lines payload},
"request2":{200-300 lines payload},
"request3":{200-300 lines payload}
etc
```

then I have function like this:

```
     def find_paths_with_value_and_replace(self, json, value_to_replace, replace_with):
        if isinstance(json, dict):
            for key, val in json.items():
                if val == value_to_replace:
                    json[key] = replace_with
                elif isinstance(val, (dict, list)):
                    self.find_paths_with_value_and_replace(val, value_to_replace, replace_with)
        elif isinstance(json, list):
            for item in json:
                self.find_paths_with_value_and_replace(item, value_to_replace, replace_with)
        return json
```

then in test I have prepare_test_data where I have values to replace like `{operation_id}` (the same name in payloads.py) and fill them with generated id with faker and return prepared json for testing.

I bet there is a better way to do that and easier, but I cannot find anything reasonable how to store those payloads and change some keys with values.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having template json files in repo and then editing all keys in prepare methods I have to edit and not using that function.

prepare methods looks like this:

```py
def prepare_something(val1,val2,val3):
    path = os.path.join(str(Path(__file__).parent), 'payloads/something.json')
    payload = helper.load_file_as_json(path))
    payload['some_key'][0]['some_ke2y'] = val1
    payload["some_key1"]["some_key2"] = val2
    payload['some_key2'] = val3
    payload['some_key3'] = helper.datetime_now('iso')
    payload["some_key4"]["some_key2"] = val1
    payload['some_key'][0]['some_key66'][0]['some_key']['some_key'] = val1
    payload['some_key'][0]['some_key66'][0]['some_key']['some_key'] = val1
    return payload
```